# Silverlight + WCF RIA service: Insert new data

Tags: silverlight, wcf-ria-services

My question look stupid... but let's ask:

I'm developing a Silverlight website... Data are on the server and I use WCF RIA and Linq to Entities to attack my data.

In My domain service of cource enable Modification on my several tables

I drop on my Silverlight app a Datagrid that fetch data on my table (let's call it tblCustomer for the example)

I've several webcast showing how easy it is to fetch data, update data BUT

**I don't know how to INSERT data!!!**

My grid is in edit mode.. but I'm not able to add a new row... and if I use the detail view.. it's the same...

Any one could provide help

Regards;

Comment: Just to clarify, is it that you cannot type a new row into a DataGrid?  Or that you cannot insert new records using the Domain Service?  Or both?

Comment: I would say both... I have some windows (pages) where I would like user to direclty type in the datagrid. I also have some Master/Details pages... And I'd like user to enter info into the details forms... because I also have several table to fill for on grid (I filled up my grid via a sql view)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For adding new item you should do it manually: add button within which create and add new Item to collection that you're representing in `DataGrid` and you'll get new item in grid.

*Note:* If you're attempting to use MVVM - do same within `ViewModel` instead code-behind.

Comment: Thanks for the answer... But acutally my problem comes from the fact I use the "Silverlight Business application". So I use all the templates. I don't know how to add this simple "new item" to my table or more precisely my itemsource... I check on the web and nothing...

Comment: @Refre Are you using [MVVM](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/advanced-techniques/the-mvvm-pattern/using-the-mvvm-pattern-in-silverlight-applications)?